# Refresh LWC after Closing Standard Edit Page

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a Lightning Web Component that displays a list of records from a custom object.  From that list, I have an action to open the standard edit page for a specific record.  How can I refresh my list once the standard edit closed?  Here is the code to open the standard edit.  Thanks!

```
   //from Product actions List - Edit Product
editCurrentRecord(currentRow) {
    //set stayOnPage to navigate back to same page after edit
  this.stayOnPage = true;
  
    // assign record id to the record edit form
  this.currentRecordId = currentRow.Id;
    // Opens the Opportunity record modal
    // to edit a particular record.
  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__objectPage',
    attributes: {
      recordId: currentRow.Id,
      objectApiName: 'opportunity_products__c',
      actionName: 'edit'
    },
    state:  {
      navigationLocation: 'RELATED_LIST'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a [RefreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-refreshview-api.html) event. When the view changes in the app, a refresh event informs components that they may need to get fresh data.

The following code should work:

```
import { registerRefreshHandler, unregisterRefreshHandler } from 'lightning/refresh';
// ...
class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
  #refreshHandlerId;
  connectedCallback() {
    this.#refreshHandlerId = registerRefreshHandler(this, () => this.refreshHandler);
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    unregisterRefreshHandler(this.#refreshHandlerId);
  }
  refreshHandler() {
    refreshApex(this.tableData);
  }
}
```

I had to check the "Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura Components" under session settings to get SFDXfox's solution to work.  thanks!

Comment: +1 Is that `#` at the beginning of `refreshHandlerId` syntactically correct?

Comment: @RahulGawale Yes, they are [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields). Cannot be accessed outside the instance they are in, and must always be referenced through `this`.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work.  It never calls the refreshHandler.  I created a separate  component just to test this with only this logic.  It only updated properly when the component was on the same page as the standard layout that I update.  The situation where I was trying to use this was opening a standard edit modal.  After the edit on the modal, the lightning-datatable was not getting updated.